# Running SQL Server Stored Procedure from Excel Issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel

I am trying to create an Excel spreadsheet that will run a run some SQL code which I have done in the past for simple select statements but now with some more advance code I keep getting an error when I try and run the SQL Server stored procedure from Excel even though it runs fine in SQL Server Management Studio.

The code of the stored procedure is:

```
truncate table LAS_RPT_IST;

insert into LAS_RPT_IST (IST_Ref_no, IST_Inv_no, LDC_ACCT_ID, IST_Commodity, IST_Tax, IST_STRS, START_DT, END_DT)
   (Select 
        th.user1_tx, th.user4_tx, ldc.ldc_acct_id,
        sum(case when th.trans_sub_ty_cd = 'ISTC' then th.trans_am end) as ISTC,
        sum(case when th.trans_sub_ty_cd = 'TAX' then th.trans_am end) as TAX,
        sum(case when th.trans_sub_ty_cd = 'STRS' then th.trans_am end) as STRS,
        th.generic1_dt, th.generic2_dt
    from 
        transaction_history th, ldc_Account ldc
    where 
        th.trans_creation_dt > = Convert(varchar(8),DateAdd(d, -1, Convert(datetime, N'20140930', 101)), 112)
        and th.user10_tx = 'IST'
        and th.ldc_acct_id = ldc.ldc_acct_id
    group by 
        th.user1_tx, th.user4_tx, ldc.ldc_acct_id, th.generic1_dt, th.generic2_dt );
```

But when I put this into Excel and try and run it I get this error

[image]

I can run select statements against the DB from Excel with no issue.

Can anyone tell me what I am missing?

Comment: Why would you put this code in your Excel spreadsheet? Turn this into a stored procedure and execute it from Excel.

Comment: Give us more info on how are you running these queries. The first thing that comes to my mind is that you cannot run more than 1 query at a time in Excel ADO - you have to run them separately.

Comment: I actually am trying to get a store procedure to run that code above is just what is in the SP.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: Thanks Marc_s the code was written by an outside consultant before my time and I am just trying to make it so users can run it without having to go into SQL studio.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to run the TRUNCATE and INSERT operations in seperate commands.